# How do I use HTML5 URLS with SpringBoot and VueJS

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following setup to my Vue project...

```js
import UploadComponent from './Upload.vue'
import MainPageComponent from './MainPage.vue'
...
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: MainPageComponent },
        { path: '/upload', component: UploadComponent }
    ]
});
...
let App = { router };
new Vue(App).$mount('#km-viewport');
```

Then in my html I have...

```html
<div id="km-viewport">
    <jg-app> </jg-app>
</div>
```

and inside the jg-app I have the following template...

```html
<md-app-content>
    <router-view></router-view>
</md-app-content>
```

Then in order to make this work with Spring Boot I add the following...

```java
@Controller
public class MainEndpoint {
  @GetMapping("")
  public String rootRedirect(){return "redirect:/ui";}
  @RequestMapping("/ui")
  public String root(){
      return "splash";
  }
  @RequestMapping("/ui/upload")
  public String upload() { return "forward:/ui"; }
}
```

The problem is whether I got to `<address>/ui` or `<address>/ui/upload` they both show the same MainPageComponent. I can't figure out how to get the upload to show the upload component.

How do I use HTML5 urls with VueJS and Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possibly a difference in how Vue is handlings the URLs.

Try activating the [**history mode** for vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html):

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',                       // <=================== added this line
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: MainPageComponent },
        { path: '/upload', component: UploadComponent }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I was about answer the same thing. I thought it would default to html5 like ng2 but then I reread the documentation.

Comment: Sure thing, this is actually a common source of problems. I think they may change the default in the next versions.

Comment: Btw, JSYK, I think you have enought reputation to do upvotes now, congratz :)